# $('className').offset().top returns weird value

Tags: jquery

When I call `$('classNameA').offset().top` in the console, it returns a value say `1236` and when I do `position = $('classNameA').offset().top` and then I output `position` in the console, it shows 1109. There are two elements named `classNameA`, if I do `$('classNameA:first-child').offset().top` and `$('classNameA:last-child').offset().top`, it outputs 1236 and 1341 respectively. Anyone know why it's like this?

Answer (score 0):

> When I call `$('classNameA').offset().top` in the console, it returns a value say 1236 and when I do `position = $('classNameA').offset().top` and then I output `position` in the console, it shows 1109.

All that means is that between those two experiments, something happened that changed the first `.classNameA` element's position.

> There are two elements named classNameA, if I do `$('classNameA:first-child').offset().top` and `$('classNameA:last-child').offset().top`, it outputs 1236 and 1341 respectively.

That tells you that the `.classNameA` which is also the first child in its parent is at 1236, and the `.classNameA` that is also the last child of its parent (apparently a different one) is at 1341.

If you use Chrome, there's a useful trick you can do: In the console, type `$(".classNameA")` and press Enter. That will list the matching elements in the console. If you right click any of the elements that are listed, you'll get a menu with the option "Reveal in Elements panel". Choosing that option takes you to the Elements panel with that specific element selected, so you can inspect its various properties (including its position), see where it is relative to other elements, etc,

Comment: thanks for the reply. But in the first question, after I output `position` value, which is 1109, and then try to see the value of `$('classNameA').offset().top`, it again outputs 1236..

Comment: @Blake: Again: That means the element has been moved between the time you assigned the top to `position` and the time you check it later. Perhaps an image above it has finished rendering, for instance. If you can create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, I can tell you what's happening.

Comment: now it's solved! Yeah, you are right, I just didn't notice that non obvious "move" of the element. thanks!

Comment: @Blake: Good deal, glad that helped.